# Wine Tasting Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability

Mr. Kim claims to be a connoisseur of wine. To test his expertise, he is given 8 cards with the names of 8 types of red wine. He is then presented 8 glasses of these wines and, after tasting them, he has to put one card at each glass. To be acknowledged as a connoisseur of wine, he should guess at least 5 names correctly.

Suppose Mr. Kim is not an expert on wines at all.

What is the probability that he will be acknowledged as a connoisseur of wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think one can use the binomial setting here, as the different choices corresponding to each wine are not pairwise independent (for instance, the last choice is totally determined by the first seven).

It's a problem of counting the number of permutations on a set of cardinality $n$ which have exactly $k$ fixed point (here $n=8$ and $k$ ranges from $5$ to $8$).

We have $P(X=k) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$

thus $P(X\ge 5)=\frac{1}{360}+\frac{1}{1440}+0+\frac{1}{40320}=\frac{141}{40320}$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You've computed a few elements of the sequence https://oeis.org/A008290 here.  In particular the OEIS gives the number of permutations of $[8]$ with $5, 6, 7, 8$ fixed points as $112, 28, 0$ and $1$ respectively, which agrees with your computation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why we have to use permutations instead of combinations? As far as I know, while the last choice is determined by the first seven, doesn't that only affect the probability of choosing the last card but not the order itself?

Comment: Denote by $G=\{1, 2, ..., 8\}$ the set of different glasses, and denote by $W=\{w_1, w_2, ..., w_8\}$ the set of different wines. Then, associating a card to each glass amounts to choosing a bijection $f: G\rightarrow W$, such that $f(i)=w_j$ if we put the card corresponding to the wine number $j$ at the glass number $i$, for all $i$, $j\in\{1, ..., 8\}$ . Thus the number of all possible choices is the number of bijections from $G$ to $W$, i.e., the number of permutations of a set of cardinality $8$.

Comment: Now let's look at is the number of correct answers. Among all these choices exist a "canonical" one: the "perfect choice", which we denote $f_0: G\rightarrow W$, that corresponds to mapping each glass to the correct wine (Mr. Kim totally ignores $f_0$,but it still exists). A random choice $f:G\rightarrow W$ made by Mr. Kim will have exactly $k$ good answers ($1\le k\le 8$) if and only if the set $\{g\in G; f(g)=f_0(g)\}$ has cardinality $k$. In other words, the set $\{g\in G; f_0^{-1}\circ f(g)=g\}$ of fixed points of the permutation $f_0^{-1}\circ f$ of $G$, has cardinality $k$. Clear enough?

Answer (score 2):

I guess via using Binomial. $P(X;r \geq 5)  $ with $p=q=1/2$ (He can only guess in right/wrong) .Thus Using $$P(X)=^{n}C_r * p^{r}*q^{n-r}$$
We get $(^8C_5+^8C_6+^8C_7+^8C_8)*\frac{1}{2^8}$.
  Please point out errors. (If any)